# discoverAllContactUserInfosWithCompletionHandler faster?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit

How can I create a CKOperation with higher priority than the default for `discoverAllContactUserInfosWithCompletionHandler`?

I can't find an example of querying all user info without using `[[CKContainer defaultContainer] discoverAllContactUserInfosWithCompletionHandler:` which is pretty low priority and takes forever to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CloudKit documentation for discoverAllContactUserInfosWithCompletionHandler says this:

> This method searches for the users asynchronously and with a low
>   priority. If you want the task to execute with a higher priority,
>   create a CKDiscoverAllContactsOperation object and configure the
>   desired priority.

You can set the priority like this:

```
var operation: CKDiscoverAllContactsOperation = CKDiscoverAllContactsOperation()
operation.queuePriority = NSOperationQueuePriority.High
```

Sample code how to use the CKDiscoverAllContactsOperation can be found here: [Any working sample code for CKDiscoverAllContactsOperation for IOS8 beta CloudKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24660018/any-working-sample-code-for-ckdiscoverallcontactsoperation-for-ios8-beta-cloudki)

Comment: I can't find a single example of "Configuring the desired priority"

Comment: I added a sample snippet.